# C# Lambda Method syntax to obtain attribute values that match pattern in LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq, lambda, linq-to-xml

I have the following XML fragment and would like to pull out the values of the status attributes that are not zero. I can obtain the elements that match the criteria but what I really want is the values of the status attributes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<response>
    <Auth status = "0">Moo</Auth>
    <Add status = "817">Cow</Add>
    <Add status = "888">Brown</Add>
    <Add status = "123">Dog</Add>
</response>
```

This lambda syntax brings back a list of the matching elements but what I need is a list of the status values not a list of the elements with those values.

```
var errcodeList = xml.Descendants("Add").Where(x => x.Attribute("status").Value != "0").Attributes("status");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `Select`, you are projecting the `IEnumerable` into another form, in this case it's a list of `x.Attributes("status").Value`

```
var errcodeList = xml.Descendants("Add")
                     .Where(x => x.Attribute("status").Value != "0")
                     .Select(x => x.Attributes("status").Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.7.2) to project the collection to the specific results that you want. For example:

```
var errcodeList = xml.Descendants("Add").Where(x => x.Attribute("status").Value != "0").Select(x => x.Attribute("status").Value);
```